# Python how to add create blocks from multiline text

Tags: python, regex, string

I have the textblock below and I am trying to separate into 3 blocks with regex.  When you see the name field it would start a new block.  How can I return all 3 blocks?

```
name: marvin
attribute: one
day: monday
dayalt: test    << this is a field that can sometimes show up
name: judy
attribute: two
day: tuesday
name: dot
attribute: three
day: wednesday
```

```
import re
lines = """name: marvin
attribute: one
day: monday
dayalt: test    << this is a field that can sometimes show up
name: judy
attribute: two
day: tuesday
name: dot
attribute: three
day: wednesday
"""

a=re.findall("(name.*)[\n\S\s]", lines, re.MULTILINE)
```

Block1 would return as "name: marvin\nattribute: one\nday: monday\ndayalt: test

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the following, which uses positive lookahead:

```py
import re

lines = """name: marvin
attribute: one
day: monday
dayalt: test
name: judy
attribute: two
day: tuesday
name: dot
attribute: three
day: wednesday"""

blocks = re.findall(r"name: .*?(?=name: |$)", lines, re.DOTALL)
print(blocks)
# ['name: marvin\nattribute: one\nday: monday\ndayalt: test\n',
#  'name: judy\nattribute: two\nday: tuesday\n',
#  'name: dot\nattribute: three\nday: wednesday']
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked great and it was easy to understand.  Was trying to figure out how to do this for over a hour!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `[\n\S\s]` (which can be written as `[\S\s]` because `\s` also matches a newline), you don't need the `re.DOTALL` flag.

But your pattern `(name.*)[\n\S\s]` only matches `name` followed by the rest of the line, and then a single any character because the character class is not repeated.

You can omit use a non greedy quantifier to prevent unnecessary backtracking, and instead match the line that starts with `name:` followed by matching all lines that do not start with it.

```
^name: .*(?:\n(?!name: ).*)*
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `name: .*` Match `name:`, a space and the rest of the line
- `(?:` Non capture group (to repeat as a whole)

  - `\n` Match a newline
  - `(?!name: ).*` Assert not `name:`  directly to the right of the current position
- `)*` Close non capture group and optionally repeat

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KkaQxW/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/dyJosJ)

Example

```
import re

pattern = r"^name: .*(?:\n(?!name: ).*)*"

lines = """name: marvin
attribute: one
day: monday
dayalt: test    << this is a field that can sometimes show up
name: judy
attribute: two
day: tuesday
name: dot
attribute: three
day: wednesday
"""

matches = re.findall(pattern, lines, re.MULTILINE)
print(matches)
```

Output

```
[
'name: marvin\nattribute: one\nday: monday\ndayalt: test    << this is a field that can sometimes show up',
'name: judy\nattribute: two\nday: tuesday',
'name: dot\nattribute: three\nday: wednesday\n'
]
```